# What is the C# equivalent to JAD?

Tags: c#, .net, disassembly, decompiler, jad

What is the C# equivalent to Java's JAD and is there a VS plugin similar to Eclipse's JadClipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best equivalent is probably [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).  It doesn't plug into Visual Studio, but it can associate with .exe and .dll files so you can open it from Windows Explorer, which I find equally if not more useful.

Comment: Thanks, this is the one I am aware of. I was hoping there was something that would integrate into Visual Studio.

Comment: I found this, perhaps it will help (haven't tried it, but it's pretty straightforward): http://blog.waltritscher.com/index.php/2006/02/25/tip-adding-reflector-to-visual-studio/